# Customizing the cursor's position in zsh

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, code-snippets

I am using [this](https://github.com/willghatch/zsh-snippets) snippet plugin in **zsh** shell and wanted to customize it.
How I can customize the cursor's position to a specific place after expanding the snippet (like the editors usually do with the completion).

I write `l` and press Ctrl-d to expand it so it becomes `$(line )` but the cursor goes after the entire snippet, I want it to be inside the snippet so I can write a number after the `line` and before the character `)`

This is the function responsible for the snippet expanding ( I still didn't edit anything from the source code, it is still the same as the repository ):

```sh
snippet-expand () {
    emulate -L zsh
    setopt extendedglob
    local MATCH
    LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%%(#m)[.\-+:|_a-zA-Z0-9]#} 
    LBUFFER+=${snippets[$MATCH]:-$MATCH} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you append to `$LBUFFER` will appear immediately to the left of the cursor. Conversely, everything you prepend to `$RBUFFER` will appear immediately to the right of the cursor. So, split your snippet into two parts and do

```
LBUFFER="$LBUFFER<left half of your snippet>"
RBUFFER="<right half of your snippet>$RBUFFER"
```